# Nest a list within a list but don't use custom bullet point in the second nested list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have created a custom bullet point IMG that works great but I want to create a second nested list within the first but the custom IMG bullet point extents to the second list when I just want it to be a normal bullet disc.

Please advise on how I can fix this issue.

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding=0;
  margin=0
}

#normal li {
  list-style-type: disc !important;
}

.africa_bullet li {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/414dNwM/Artboard-3-copy-14.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="africa_bullet li" id="black">
  <li>B-BBEE Compliance/Advisory
    <br>

    <ul id="normal_li">
      <li>B-BBEE Strategy & Alignment</li>
      <br>
      <li>Optimisation of B-BBEE Level</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```css
ul.africa_bullet {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding=0;
  margin=0
}

.africa_bullet  {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/414dNwM/Artboard-3-copy-14.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#normal {
  list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="africa_bullet li" id="black">
  <li>B-BBEE Compliance/Advisory
    <br>

    <ul id="normal_li">
      <li>B-BBEE Strategy & Alignment</li>
      <br>
      <li>Optimisation of B-BBEE Level</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```